# JSON.parse, Sinatra and Webrick

Tags: json, sinatra

Trying to figure out why this

```
get '/json_test' do
  j = '{"key1": "val1"}'
  JSON.parse(j)
end
```

causes this error

> Internal Server Error
>
> can't convert Array into String

using the pry gem I am able to hit a breakpoint before the parsing. From there I can call JSON.parse(j) and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're serving *code* from the route. `JSON.parse` converts a string of JSON into a Ruby data type. The last expression from a Sinatra route should either be the body string, or an array that conforms to Rack's `[status_code, headers, body]` (or almost). If you wish the route to receive JSON, try this:

```
get '/json_test' do
  j = '{"key1": "val1"}'
  JSON.parse(j)
  halt 200
end
```

But it shouldn't be a GET unless you're going to respond with something meaninful in the body.

Comment: so it's not JSON.parse that is failing. It's the sinatra failing when it can't covert the results of JSON.parse to a string? That makes a lot of sense actually. I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @DerrickW Yes. Well, it's not actually failing, it's doing what it's supposed to :) See [the docs on return values for the detail](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Return%20Values).